# why the difference between plot produced by glm() and polynomial()

Tags: r, logistic-regression, polynomials

```
library(polynom)
set.seed(12345)
x<-seq(1,5,0.01)
lp<-rnorm(401,-0.7,1)-20*x+7*x^2
link_lp <- exp(lp)/(1 + exp(lp))
y<-(runif(401) < link_lp)
f<-glm(y~poly(x,degree=2),family="binomial")
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(x,f$linear.predictors)
plot(polynomial(coef(f)),xlim=c(1,5))
plot(x,f$fitted)
```

Figures produced with above codes

[image]

the figures produced by linear predictor and polynomial() are supposed to be the same, but actually they are different. what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study `help("poly")` and need to learn what an orthogonal polynomial is.

```
f<-glm(y~poly(x,degree=2, raw = TRUE),family="binomial")
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(x,f$linear.predictors)
plot(polynomial(coef(f)),xlim=c(1,5))
plot(x,f$fitted)
```

[image: resulting plot]